# get values of display:table columns to action class struts2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, decorator, displaytag

I am creating a table using display tag in JSP, and I'm using decorator to display the last column(`Action`) which is a link to my action class.

```
<display:table id='listDisplay' name='detailsList' list='detailsList' requestURI=""  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" decorator="com.abc.RecBackupDetailsDecorator">
    <display:column title="Rule Name" property="rulename"></display:column>
    <display:column title="Campaign" property="campname"></display:column>
    <display:column title="Dispositions" property="dispositions"></display:column>
    <display:column title="Backup Server" property="backupserver"></display:column>
    <display:column title="Backup Directory" property="backupdir"></display:column>
    <display:column title="Frequency" property="frequency"></display:column>
    <display:column title="Added On" property="addedon"></display:column>
    <display:column title="Last Run Date" property="lastrundate"></display:column>
    <display:column title="Status" property="status"></display:column>
    <display:column title="Action" property="editDetails"></display:column>
</display:table>
```

Decorator Class :

```
public class RecBackupDetailsDecorator extends TableDecorator {

public String getEditDetails() {
    System.out.println("Index of List : " + getViewIndex());
    String editDetails = "<a href='editDetailsRecBackupConf.action' class='editDetails'>Edit</a>";
    return editDetails;
}
}
```

Now, when I click on edit, I want to get the values of display-table columns in my action class method (`editDetailsRecBackupConf`) but don't know how can I get the values in my action class.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an ajax call to the action class.

```
<script>
function passValueToAction(val)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","myActionClass.action?value="+val,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

suppose on clicking edit link , js function `passValueToAction(val)` is called where `val` is the value you need to pass to action. Here the action class called is `myActionClass.action` along with query parameters.

Register your action call in  `struts2.xml` (config xml) to map this action call to the action class and give the method you want to call.